# How to set intellij remote debug?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I am trying to debug my app in testing environment, my app is running in pod, I said 'pod' because I am not familiar with *Kubernetes*, its manage client looks like this:[app running schematic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjRjf.png). I have learn I should set idea like this [idea RUN/Debug Configurations schematic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brm2d.png). And should restart and redeploy my app, I changed Dockfile firstly. the origin instruction is `FROM xxx/java:alpine VOLUME /tmp ADD recruitment.jar app.jar ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx2048m","-jar","/app.jar"]` and I changed this to `FROM xxx/java:alpine VOLUME /tmp ADD recruitment.jar app.jar ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005","-jar","/app.jar"]`  but it always show error like this `Error running 'face_remote': Unable to open debugger port (888.88.888.888[not real]:5005): java.io.IOException "handshake timeout"`. I am not sure with this ip,sicne I use 'ping 888.88.888.888' instruction can not success. I use this ip because Swagger request url's domain name's ip is this.this main [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgh91.png). and I guess if the app is running in docker or k8s and it will have a different Interactive mode. not same like just running in linux

Answer (score 0):

most of the attached image are not visible.

- IP address should be accessible from your local system
  [888.88.888.888] note sure this is correct.
- debug port also need to be mapped from your local system
  -use port forwarding
  ex:kubectl port-forward  5005:5005

If you have  configure port forwarding then you can use localhost:5005 for debugging

Answer (score 0):

I see three things that you can check:

**Check the IP address:**
The jar file runs inside a Docker container, which runs inside a pod. To access the pod you usually go through a service and an ingress. The ip you are using is most likely hitting the ingress/service or any other higher layer.

To attach a remote debugger, you will need to connect **directly to the PodIP**. One way of doing this is to first connect to your kubernetes cluster using the tool *kubectl* (some configuration required) and make a port forward from your pod: `kubectl port-forward my-pod-c93b8b6df-8c4aa 5005:5005` pod (as an example, the pod instance name is my-pod-c93b8b6df-8c4aa).

This will open a connection from your local computer into the pod. Then you will need to identify the PodIP by `kubectl describe pods my-pod-c93b8b6df-8c4aa` and use that in IntelliJ

**Check if the port is exposed:**
Make sure you expose the port `5005` from the pod in your test environment (similar to exposing a port when you run the container locally).

How to do this depends a bit on how you are running your Kubernetes cluster. If you use Helm chart, you can just add a configuration like this in the port section of your deployment yaml:

```
- containerPort: 5005
  name: debug
  protocol: TCP
```

**Check debug-command address:**
Last thing is to make sure you are adding the correct address in the command line option. As IntelliJ suggest in the debug editor: for JDK9+ use `…suspend=n,address=*:5005` and for JDK8 and below use `…suspend=n,address=5005`